# perl Net::Frame::Layer::8021X module not found

Tags: perl, authentication, module

Having trouble trying to get passed this last dependency for an old Cisco dump.pl script.

https://supportforums.cisco.com/blog/154046

So far I've installed the following dependencies:

```
apt-get install libclass-gomor-perl libnet-libdnet-perl libnet-pcap-perl libbit-vector-perl libnetpacket-perl
```

and placed all of his custom perl modules in a Net/ directory

then finally I run

```
./dump.pl
```

My output:

```
*** Net::Frame::Layer::8021X module not found.
*** Either install it (if avail), or implement it.
*** You can also send the pcap file to perl@gomor.org.
Frame number: 11 (length: 60)
Frame NUMBER 11 SSL FOUND, preparing SSL payload and crafting TCP packet
*** Net::Frame::Layer::8021X module not found.
*** Either install it (if avail), or implement it.
*** You can also send the pcap file to perl@gomor.org.
Frame number: 12 (length: 64)
Frame NUMBER 12 SSL FOUND, preparing SSL payload and crafting TCP packet
*** Net::Frame::Layer::8021X module not found.
*** Either install it (if avail), or implement it.
*** You can also send the pcap file to perl@gomor.org.
Frame number: 13 (length: 61)
Frame NUMBER 13 SSL FOUND, preparing SSL payload and crafting TCP packet
```

After debugging using `perl -d dump.pl`, I saw that it actually requires the modules Net::Frame::Layer::ETH and Net::Frame::Layer::8021X. The former I have and the latter is missing.

```
Net::Frame::Simple::unpack(Net/Frame/Simple.pm:98):
98:    for (1..1000) {
  DB<4> n
Net::Frame::Simple::unpack(Net/Frame/Simple.pm:99):
99:       last unless $raw;
  DB<4> n
Net::Frame::Simple::unpack(Net/Frame/Simple.pm:101):
101:          $encapsulate =~ s/[^-:\w]//g; # Fix potential code injection
  DB<4> n
Net::Frame::Simple::unpack(Net/Frame/Simple.pm:102):
102:          my $layer = 'Net::Frame::Layer::'.$encapsulate;
  DB<4> n
Net::Frame::Simple::unpack(Net/Frame/Simple.pm:103):
103:          eval "require $layer";
  DB<4> n
```

So I installed these dependencies:

```
apt-get install cpanminus
cpanm Net::Frame
cpanm Net::Frame::Simple
cpanm Net::Frame::Layer
cpanm Socket6
```

I'm still hitting the same issue.

With additional debugging it seems that the issue is with `raw        => $h->{raw}` because I ran `print Net::Frame::Simple->new( firstLayer => $h->{firstLayer}, timestamp  => $h->{timestamp} )` and `print $h->{raw}` in the interpreter without triggering the issue.

```
main::(dump.pl:44):     my $f = Net::Frame::Simple->new(
main::(dump.pl:45):         raw        => $h->{raw},
main::(dump.pl:46):         firstLayer => $h->{firstLayer},
main::(dump.pl:47):         timestamp  => $h->{timestamp},
main::(dump.pl:48):     );
```

It will write out an ssl.pcap file but it will not contain the raw packet data, just the firstLayer e.g. ETH and the UNIX timestamp. I also made sure that I'm using the local modules inside the Net/ directory by replacing all of the `use` statements with `require` and replacing the :: with /.

Still complains when trying to `require Net::Frame::Layer::8021X` which doesn't seem to exist anywhere on the Internet...

Comment: You are missing the _following statement_ where the code is failing. Please add it.

Comment: @simbabque, I don't understand. Which statement am I missing? It seems to me that the module is missing or has never been written / been released to the public? I contacted the developer of dump.pl and he explained that he cannot find the module. Then I contacted the developer of Net::Frame::Layer and he said the 8021X module needs to be written.

Comment: In you question you have _the following statement_, but then nothing. That was not diagnosis, just pointing out that information on the question is missing. You probably forgot it. ;-)

Comment: @simbabque, ah ok thank you. Yeah the statement is just requiring that missing module. It would appear this module needs to be written.